# shared library "obfuscation" - stripping all symbols/strings on internal api; symbold paths starts with PN4, N2, N3, N4

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, strip

I am integrating one specific proprietary library - which is provided in a form of static library (lets say libBla.a). They have wild requirements on "obfuscation" - meaning after linking against their libraries we have to remove all mentions of their methods and even namespaces from resulting production library.

So far so good.. strip and few cmake lines can remove symbols.
`nm -D libsomething.so | grep -i bla` returns no hits.

However when running strings on the library I still see those symbols there.
But these "symbols" are something weird, which even demangler cannot decompose.

```
strings libsomething.so | grep -i bla
PN4something_namespace13BlaObserverIN3Bla_namespace6IBlaClassINS1_8BlaClassInterfaceINS1_13BlaClass14ImplementationEEENS1_10BlaClassInterfaceINS1_15BlaClass14ImplementationEEEE14BlaClassInterfaceINS1_12IBlaAnotherClassENS1_14IBlaClassListenerEEEEE
PN4something_namespace13BlaObserverIN3Bla_namespace16IBlaClassINS1_21BlaAnotherClass14ImplementationEE9BlaListenerInterfaceEEE
PN4something_namespace13BlaObserverIN3Bla_namespace8BlaClassInterfaceINS1_13BlaClass14ImplementationEE9BlaListenerInterfaceEEE
....
```

So what are these strings/symbols starting with **PN4 / N2 / N3 / N4** and where are they coming from?

Why is c++ demangler not able to translate them?

Answer (score 1):

After lot of hussle I found out that the symbols are coming from RTTI usage.
We use templates for integration of their classes, and in some of our methods we want to distinguish the template class type used with `typeid`, which is ugly but it solves some workarounds.

The solution was to stop using typeid and add this to cmake:

`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-rtti")`